# PyQt5 : How to delete widget once video gets over and put a picture at the place of video player

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, video, pyqt, pyqt5

i am new to Pyqt5. I designed an UI using Pyqt5 designer which has a QmainWindow inside which i had placed QWidget. In QWidget i had placed QHBoxlayout which contains a QFrame. This QFrame i used to contain QVideoWidget.
QVideoWidget is used to play a video file. What i am trying to achive is to 
1.) Pause the video when it reaches the last frame of video while playing. 
Or 
1.) Once the video is over then i replace the player with a picture in the same Frame which was used to hold the video player.

Inorder to achive the above i have written below code --

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'video_1.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!



from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
import sys
import time
import sip


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1119, 891)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 10, 711, 841))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.widget_2 = QVideoWidget(self.frame)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 681, 771))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1119, 23))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def run(self, fileName):
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.widget_2)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
        self.player.play()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.run("/home/shantanu/UI/intro.mp4")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What i thought was if i am able to get the total duration of the video before it starts playing then by using combination of while and if loop i can pause the video when it reaches its total duration. 
Code for that was --

```
def run(self, fileName):
    self.player = QMediaPlayer()
    self.player.setVideoOutput(self.widget_2)
    self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))

    from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
    clip = VideoFileClip("/home/shantanu/UI/intro.mp4")
    print( int(clip.duration) )

    # Assume the clip = 6

    i = 0
    while i < 6:
        self.player.play()
        i = i+1
        if i == 5 :
            self.video.pause()
```

But the above approach does't worked. Because as soon as i execute the file everything gets executed and i am not able to achive what i wanted to do.

The code runs fine without any error but i am not able to get what i am trying to get.

I tried to use deleteLater() function provided by the Pyqt5 but that also does't worked.
Below is the best way which can be done but i am not able to do it. I went through similar questions on Stackoveflow but was not able to achieve the desired results.

## Can anyone please guide me how to use remove widget once used and then i replace it with a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [signal] void QMediaPlayer::**mediaStatusChanged**(QMediaPlayer::MediaStatus status)
>
> Signals that the status of the current media has changed.
>
> Note: Notifier signal for property mediaStatus.
>
> See also mediaStatus().

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer
#import sip


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1119, 891)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 10, 711, 841))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("horizontalLayoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.frame.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.frame.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.widget_2 = QVideoWidget(self.frame)
        self.widget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 381, 371))  # 20, 40, 681, 771
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.widget_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.widget_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.widget_2.setObjectName("widget_2")
        
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1119, 23))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def run(self, fileName):
        self.player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.widget_2)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))

        self.player.mediaStatusChanged.connect(self.media_status)         # <---
        
        self.player.play()
        
    def media_status(self, status):                                       # <---
        if status == 7:
            print("The End!")
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("The End!", self.centralwidget, 
                                          alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            self.label.setStyleSheet("""
                QLabel { 
                    background-color : blue; 
                    color : #fff; 
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 32px;
                }
            """)
            self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 50, 381, 371))
            self.label.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.run("D:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Test/video5.avi")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]